# How to update a text within NSView?

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsview

I want to update a text that is added via `drawInRect: withAttributes:` in `NSView`. However, it seems that the text cannot be updated by just changing its property.

```
class MyView: NSView {
    var str: NSString!

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        str = "Sample Text"
        str.drawInRect(NSMakeRect(0, 0, 60, 40), withAttributes: nil)
    }
}
```

The code above creates the text `Sample Text` to the view, which I added on the storyboard.

However, when I tried to update the text either by changing its property or calling `drawInRect: withAttributes:` again, the text wasn't updated at all. Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func callButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        myView.str = "Test"
        myView.str.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40), withAttributes: nil)
}
```

Why is the text not updated? Also, how can I update the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not override `str` in `drawRect`. Instead, set a default string to the property in initialization, and use `setNeedsDisplay` to mark the view as dirty when you update the `str` property.